# Split String in Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a String like this

```
//ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf
```

and want to get last part of

```
00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf
```

Answer (score 21):

Let's say you have

```
text="//ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf"
```

If you know the position, i.e. in this case the 9th, you can go with

```
echo "$text" | cut -d'/' -f9
```

However, if this is dynamic and your want to split at "/", it's safer to go with:

```
echo "${text##*/}"
```

This removes everything from the beginning to the last occurrence of "/" and should be the shortest form to do it.

For more information on this see: [Bash Reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

For more information on `cut` see: [cut man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/)

Comment: `${text##*/}` is not only shortest, but also much more efficient than the `echo | cut` approach. One gotcha -- you need to add quotes; otherwise, the text can be string-split rejoined by echo; to see why that can cause bugs, try running this code with `IFS=-` or, worse, `IFS=0`.

Comment: ...so, `echo "${text##*/}"`, **with the quotes**, is the safe and efficient approach.

Comment: And what if I want to take the first part? What's the name? How can I search online to find variants?

Comment: "First part" really depends on the form the string is set up and what you define it to be. To e.g. grab the "ABC" in my example, `echo $text | cut -d'/' -f3` will provide it.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the quotes. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: This is the best method for me. So clean and simple.

Answer (score 7):

The tool `basename` does exactly that:

```
$ basename //ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf  
00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you want more than just the last part of the path, 
you could do something like this:

```
  echo $PWD | rev | cut -d'/' -f1-2 | rev
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `bash` string function:

```
$ string="//ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf"
```

```
$ echo "${string##*/}"
00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf
```

But following are some **other** options:

```
$ awk -F'/' '$0=$NF' <<< "$string"
00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf
```

```
$ sed 's#.*/##g' <<< "$string"
00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf
```

**Note:** `<<<` is `herestring` notation. They **do not** create a subshell, however, they are **NOT** portable to POSIX sh (as implemented by shells such as ash or dash).

Comment: I'd worry more about portability to POSIX sh (as implemented by modern shells such as ash and dash) than portability to Bourne (which predates it by decades). If we had to provide disclaimers whenever something wasn't portable to Bourne, we wouldn't have `$(( 1 + 1 ))` or `"$(some-command "$(other-command)")"` either.

Comment: ...really, for all that bash's name says "Bourne Again", it's more of an enhanced derivative of the Korn shell (an early version of which the POSIX sh standard was loosely based on). The point of which being -- Bourne is really, **really** ancient.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for the insight. My experience with *nix is nothing compared to yours. Ill reference your comments in the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. If I'm going to be a pedant, least I can do is try to be a helpful one. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your pedantic nature is an excellent source for learning.

Comment: (well -- I said "decades", but it's not really a full 20 years; Bourne shell is from '77, whereas POSIX sh was specified in 1992).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this BASH regex:

```
s='//ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf'
[[ "$s" =~ [^/]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in awk:

```
string="//ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf"

echo "${string}" | awk -v FS="/" '{ print $NF }'
```

Use "/" as field separator and print the last field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
echo //ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```